# Is there any undesirable effect doing ModelState.Clear() before action executing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, modelstate

If we are using ajax call to return partial view, then response from the action method may return cached output from partial view. The issue has been discussed on several SO post [here](http://MVC%203%20+%20$.ajax%20-%20response%20seems%20to%20be%20caching%20output%20from%20partial%20view), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027839/mvc-partial-view-model-not-refreshing), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775170/asp-net-mvc-modelstate-clear)

To resolve issue i have to do `ModelState.Clear()` in action method.

I have several action methods that returns partial view using Ajax call. So i thought instead of doing ModelState.Clear() in each method i can create custom `ActionFilterAttribute` like below

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {            
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Clear();
        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
 }
```

and then register it with global filters

```
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {                    
        filters.Add(new NoCacheAttribute());
    }
```

This seems to be working fine.

However I wanted to know if there is there any undesirable effect doing `ModelState.Clear()` before action executing? If not, then why that is not a default behavior in asp.net mvc

Comment: using `ModelState.Clear()` has nothing to do with cached output

Comment: It does. Please see the links provided. Also `NoCacheAttribute` is just a name of the class. May be the name of the class is confusing

Comment: No it does not! And your first link does not work. The 2nd link is because the parameter is the same as the model property so its added to `ModelState`. And ditto for the 3rd (the accepted answer claims its a bug but its not. And to explain why, refer the 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111)

Comment: You have not shown your method and its parameters or the model but I assume you have the same issue as per the 2nd link. Which is easily solved by using a different name for the parameter. Again - its not being cached - its constructing a new model

Comment: And are there side effects - yes, none of your POST methods will ever be able to test `ModelState.IsValid`